# Cannot stop properly all threads in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, token, threadpool

I'm trying in c# to stop all threads with token or thread.abort, but both don't work properly

```
                int workerThreads = 1;
                int portThreads = 0;

                ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreads, portThreads);
                ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(workerThreads,portThreads);
                foreach (string d in list)
                {
                    var p = d;
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                    {
                        this.checker(p,cts.Token);
                    });
                }`
```

The function called with checker is built as follow:

```
    private void checker(string f, object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)obj;

            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Stopped", "Checker aborted");
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            } //etc main features of fucntion are hidden from here
```

I want to stop properly all threads when i call the cts.Cancel(); but every time appears: Stopped , checker aborted and not only for one time but maybe it is shown for every thread process. How can i show the message one time and stopping all threads in the same moment?
I want also set a number of maximum threads that should work before to proceed with Others. I tried with SetMaxThreads but neither this seems to work.

Comment: Why are you starting a Thread to start a new Thread? Also, why are you mixing Threads with TPL?

Comment: I took this example from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235651/multithreaded-proxy-checker

Comment: Trying to set the maximum threads to 1 cannot have the desired  effect, the ThreadPool class will silently increase it to the number of processor cores.  Always more than 1 on a modern machine.  No point in doing this, simply start a *single* thread and have it iterate the list.  That loop is also the correct place for the token.IsCancellationRequested test, right now it never works because it is never true right at the start of the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the comments for the best practice advises, because what you are doing here is not completely correct, but to achieve your goal you can use a flag combined with lock like this:

```
private static object _lock = new object();
private static bool _stoppedNotificationShown = false;
private void checker(string f, object obj)
{
    try
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)obj;

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            lock(_lock) {
                if (!_stoppedNotificationShown) {
                    _stoppedNotificationShown = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Stopped", "Checker aborted");
                }
            }
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        } //etc main features of fucntion are hidden from here
```

Comment: i tried but threads don't terminate in few seconds , to stop entire process it takes at least one minute... how can i improve this? If i also try to start again the same process not quitting the program that thread function seems don't work anymore

Comment: First, you should prefer Tasks over threads. Second, keep in mind that `MessageBox.Show` blocks the thread until the message box is not closed.

Comment: message box is only to show what happens it will be removed... if i want to change it with tasks i have to use await and async function in order to have the same result? The real problem is that once executed the code i can't run the same again i have to close and reopen the program because i can't close and reopen threads. If there is a solution to this i'll appreciate so much.

Comment: i'm solving using asynctask (expecially await Task.WhenAll ) the proelem is that i can't send the cancelation token with task.whenall beacuse it wait all tasks before to proceed (that is what i want but cancellation token should work in whetever case). That's the last problem, i solved others...

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848606/how-to-safely-cancel-a-task-using-a-cancellationtoken-and-await-task-whenall?rq=1) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2704)